# « Il nous restent des efforts à faire » ?

Tags: verbes, accord

Faut-il accorder le verbe avec le sujet ou avec l'object direct — ce qui n'est pas le cas normal mais qui quand même est assez naturel! — dans ce cas?

> Il nous restent des efforts à faire.

ou

> Il nous reste des efforts à faire.

?

Answer (score 3):

*Il* est le sujet de *reste* et emporte l'accord :

> Il nous reste des efforts à faire.

D'ailleurs *[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Il%20nous%20restent%20des%2C%20Il%20nous%20reste%20des%20%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIl%20nous%20reste%20des%3B%2Cc0)* ne propose que cette solution.

Pour mettre le verbe au pluriel, il faut un sujet pluriel

> Des efforts restent à faire par nous-mêmes.

... c'est une tournure peu usitée qui insiste plus sur qui doit faire l'effort que sur l'effort lui-même.

Comment: Peu usitée et assez contorsionée! ;-)

Comment: Grevisse écrit que quand *rester* précède le sujet et est vu comme impersonel on écrit tant «Reste les procedures» comme (plus frequemment) «restent les apparences», mais dans ces cas il y a une invesion. C'est ça que j'avais dans la mémoire, j'imagine.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez -- 1) En effet, mais dans une phrase plus élaborée : *Des efforts importants restent à faire en amont par les fournisseurs pour les livraisons en temps utile, et surtout par nous mêmes pour les finitions.* -- 2) «restent les apparences» certes, mais sans *nous* :)